# Get data from other RESTful Server and save DB in Spring

Tags: spring, rest, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

Most of cases, views(JSP) use RESTful server to extract desired data.

In my case, a wep application server itself needs to extract data from other web server which provides RESTful. And it needs to periodcally update data into database without users request.

As far as I know, Web Application Server is in operation when there is a requst by a user.
If it is difficult in implementing through scheduling, would you recommand to use the following method?

1. A user requests by specific URI
2. A view is shown which telling user for a wait.
3. A controller gets initial information from DAO(Persistance/Service class)
4. A controller(it may be the other type of class) requests data from other RESTful server using the initial information as parameters
5. A controller receives data and stores into databases by using DAO
6. A controller sends messege to a view for telling the task has been done.

**System / Framework dependency : JSP, Spring-MVC, Tomcat**

Thank you in advance, any advice will be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring has a whole [Task Execution](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) chapter on handling this use case by creating `@Scheduled` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Scheduler (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/):

> Quartz is a richly featured, open source job scheduling library that
>   can be integrated within virtually any Java application

Some examples at
[Quartz Scheduler Tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

There are certain number of ways which can fit into this scenario as a solution :

1. Ticketing - Depending upon the usecase we can integrate a ticketing system like serviceNow, Remedy and ITSM into the application and schedule the operation. Involves concept like Polling.
2. Using @Scheduled annotation to schedule the tasks which are to be implemented ["schedule-tasks-ref"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Please feel free to ask if you want any clarification on this or else you have usecases that are not met by these solutions offered.